# Не могу достать kwargs в сериализаторе DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Мне нужно создать отметку рейтинга и в поле profile вставить данные из Url (kwargs['user__id'])
Однако у меня не получается

Есть **модель**:

```py
class Rating(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rating", 
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    rating = models.IntegerField()  
    ...
```

*Важная деталь - в модели Profile есть поле user у которого есть id, вот по нему я и ссылаюсь, т.е user__id*

**Urls:**

```py
path('profile/<int:user__id>/rating/add/', views.RatingAdd.as_view()),
```

**Сериализатор:**

```py
class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Рейтинг специалистов

    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['rating']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rating = Rating.objects.create(profile=Profile.objects.get(user__id=self.kwargs['user__id']), **validated_data)
        return rating
```

И собственно **Views**

```py
class RatingAdd(generics.CreateAPIView):
    # Отправка оценки специалисту

    queryset = Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RatingSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

В конце всего этого мне выдает ошибку:
**'RatingSerializer' object has no attribute 'kwargs'**

Answer (score 0):

**Проблема решена, я убрал метод create из сериализатора и переписал View:**

```py
class RatingAdd(generics.GenericAPIView):
    # Отправка оценки специалисту

    serializer_class = serializers.RatingSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, user__id):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(profile=Profile.objects.get(user__id=self.kwargs['user__id']))

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```